# Recursion to reverse a digit

Tags: c++, recursion

How recursion works in this problem I am not getting please help as it is returning rev_num so I am confused.

```
 #include <stdio.h>;

    /* Recursive function to reverse digits of num*/
    int reversDigits(int num)
    {
      static int rev_num = 0;
      static int base_pos = 1;
      if(num > 0)
      {
        reversDigits(num/10);
        rev_num  += (num%10)*base_pos;
        base_pos *= 10;
      }
      return rev_num;
    }

    /*Driver program to test reversDigits*/
    int main()
    {
        int num = 4562;
        printf("Reverse of no. is %d", reversDigits(num));

        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You lack some information: What is the actual and expected output?

Comment: Using a debugger will help you greatly. Using a debugger you can step through the code, line by line, and step into the recursive calls, all while being able to see the values of all involved variables and how they change. Knowledge of and being able to use a debugger is a *crucial* skill as a programmer.

Comment: Does it work, and you are asking why?

Comment: @ThomasChristensen Check this see recursive way http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-reverse-digits-of-a-number/

Comment: The `static` variables are the key to understanding why it works.

Comment: @ThomasChristensen will please explain me I am not getting, it is the most difficult recursive programs I have ever seen

Comment: @ThomasChristensen,@Joachim Pileborg what is the use of static variables here what do they do?

Comment: You should really use a debugger to trace it step by step, then you would understand. Explaining it would take up a lot space and time. So learn about debugging and the C stack with recursion: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson16.html

Comment: `static` variables: http://geeksquiz.com/static-variables-in-c/

Comment: @ThomasChristensen Ok I will see it thanks

Answer (score 0):

you must return the name of function like :

```
return reversDigits(num);
```

Comment: so only change I should make in above code is return reversDigits(num);

Comment: yes but i think , is better to use IF statement for this code

Comment: @scbas The OP's code works and it is recursive (function calls itself in if statement). It is using static varibles to remember the partial result between recursive contexts.